# Is this the efficient BST Insertion?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I implemented the Binary Search Tree Insertion method on my own just based on logic.
So, can anyone verify that the code is working fine while inserting and searching( use your own searching methods like inorder, preorder, postorder)?

And also find the time complexity of the code.

```
public void insert(int data) {
    Node node = new Node(data);
    if (root == null) {
        root = node;
        size++;
    } else {
        Node n = root;
        if (data > n.data) {
            while (n.right != null) {
                n = n.right;
            }
            if (data < n.data) {
                while (n.left != null) {
                    n = n.left;
                }
                if (data != n.data) {
                    n.left = node;
                    size++;
                }
            } else {
                if (data != n.data) {
                    n.right = node;
                    size++;
                }
            }
        } else if (data < n.data) {
            while (n.left != null) {
                n = n.left;
            }
            if (data > n.data) {
                while (n.right != null) {
                    n = n.right;
                }
                if (data != n.data) {
                    n.right = node;
                    size++;
                }
            } else {
                if (data != n.data) {
                    n.left = node;
                    size++;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Edit :- I found a problem when i insert these numbers:-

```
    bst.insert(10);
    bst.insert(11);
    bst.insert(90);
    bst.insert(13);
    bst.insert(12);
    bst.insert(70);
    bst.insert(80);
```

it prints like this(inorder):-
10 11 80 70 12 13 90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be a few issues with your code:

```
if (data > n.data) {
    while (n.right != null) {
                n = n.right;
                .
                .
                }
           }
```

means that given a tree like:

```
  10
 /  \
8    15
    / \
   12  23
         \
          26
         /
       20
```

And asking to insert for example 21, the given algorithem would attempt to insert it in the left child of 26. However this node is already taken, hence your algorithem is flawed.
I would suggest that you call insertion from each node recursively like:

```
// in class tree
public void insert(int data) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(data);
    } 
    else {
        root.insert(data);
    }
    size++;
}
//in class Node
public void insert(int data) {
    if(data>=this.data){
         if(right==null) right=new Node(data)
         else right.insert(data);
    }
    else{
         if(left==null) left=new Node(data)
         else left.insert(data);
    }
}
```

Since each node is responsible for checking if its children are empty before insertion this problem wont repeat.

In terms of complexity:
you can get a tree like

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
     \
      ...
        \
         n
```

Where inserting a value bigger than n would result in passing over n nodes, therefore time complexity is O(n).